# ECONNREFUSED during socket connect in Node app on Openshift

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, openshift

ECONNREFUSED on socket connect in Node app on openshift servers, works on development machine.

Hi, I am trying to write simple app that needs to make a outgoing socket connection from my server.js ( that came with the pre-installed template). In my express routes i have something like

```
self.createRoutes = function() {
self.routes = { };
self.routes['/asciimo'] = function(req, res) {
    var link = "http://i.imgur.com/kmbjB.png";
    res.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "' /></body></html>");
};

self.routes['/mycfg'] = function(req, res) {
    var serviceSocket = new net.Socket();
    serviceSocket.connect({port: 443, host:"www.google.com",localAddress:self.ipaddress}, function() {
        console.log("connected!!");

    });
    serviceSocket.on("error", function (e) {
        console.log("Could not connect to service " + e);
    });
}
```

} 
The self.address is t process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP which is 127.4.217.129 in my case.
I tried the code on my development machine it works fine. But fails with ECONNREFUSED on openshift servers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Node version 0.6.25. I created a new app with node verison 0.10 and the same code works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this instead

```
var host = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
    wss = new WebSocketServer({host: host, port: port});
    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
      ws.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        ws.send(message);
      });
      ws.send('something');
    });
```

**EDIT**

My apologies I overlooked that you were making an external connection. After reproducing it locally I was able to connect by removing the `localAddress` on your `Sockect.connect`. After looking at the documentation and source a bit this makes sense. Making a connection to google and binding to a local ip won't work due to google not knowing this local ip.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your reply. By removing `localAddress` it still shows `ECONNREFUSED` on openshift servers. I also tried my public openShift URL "...rhcloud.com" but same result.

Comment: Thats strange, I ran this

Comment: Weird, I ran this http://pastebin.com/SfDGC84n on my gear with node 0.10.5 and I'm able to connect

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did a console.log(process.versions) and found that node version on my opneshift application is 0.6.20. I changed my node engine version to > = 0.10.0 in package.json but it does not seem to make a effect. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Update i tried 'echo "0.10.15 >> .openshift/markers/NODEJS_VERSION' and pushing the changes but the version still remains at 0.6.20